# facebook like button showing extra information

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook button tag (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and used this tag

```
<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/" send="false" show_faces="false" ></fb:like>
```

But it is showing me more than I asked for. It works fine in firefox but it shows some extra information on safari. How can I get rid of that signup link?

[image]

Comment: I assume that you are using a custom tag for this? Can we see the code there?

Comment: Based on what Alvaro posted, the way to get rid of it is to sign in to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

AS Scott indicated I think this is working as designed. When in Firefox you are likely signed into facebook - hence the like button displays as you want it to display. But when you are in Safari you are NOT logged in (there's no facebook cookie - probably because you use FF as your default browser).  So you get the info and the signup button.

As for the "extra" information you should experiment with

```
type="box_count"
```

and or

```
type="button_count"
```

The default is "standard" - so perhaps one of the other types will be more suited to your layout.

Answer (score -1):

if you aren't connected to Facebook, you will always see the Sign Up button, if you don't Want  show the Sign Up link, you can use a div container with Overflow:hidden property

```
<div class="containerLike">
<fb:like href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/" send="false" show_faces="false" ></fb:like>
</div>
```

and in css:

```
.containerLike {overflow:hidden; 
  width: Your selected width;}
```

Comment: Not sure this is a viable solution as the width will vary with the number of people who liked it. Make it too wide and you might still see part of the 'Sign up' message, make it too narrow and you might not see the full part of the message you want to see.

Comment: Yah. i'm an idiot you're right, 1.500.000 users was for the Fb like plugin .